# Can't draw connection from anything to destination schema in BizTalk Mapper

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-mapper

I'm new to BizTalk, so forgive me if I'm not using the correct terminology.  Anyways, I've created a composite Schema with two tables that I'd like to insert into, it's basically like this:

```
<xs:element name="StorageLocationImport">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="mxstoreloc:Insert" /> 
            <xs:element ref="mxin:Insert" /> 
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

In the mapper, I'm able to map anything to `mxstoreloc:Insert` with no issue.  When I try to map **anything** to `mxin:Insert`, the connection doesn't work.  I drag the line, I get the crosshairs cursor (I've seen people before get the crossed-out-circle cursor, mine doesn't switch to that) and then when I let go the line disappears instead of connecting.

I went into the schema and created a second `mxin:Insert` node, so it looked like this:

```
<xs:sequence>
    <xs:element ref="mxstoreloc:Insert" /> 
    <xs:element ref="mxin:Insert" /> 
    <xs:element ref="mxin:Insert" /> 
</xs:sequence>
```

And for some reason that allowed me to make the connection (to either element), but if I deleted either of the two, the connections would disappear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue [mostly] lies within the map itself, not either of the schemas or connections.

In the `Grid Properties` window, by default, `Ignore Namespaces for Links` is set to `True`.  Since I have multiple elements which are named `Insert`(even though the namespaces are different), the XML Mapper gets confused.  To fix this, simply turn `Ignore Namespaces for Links` to `False`.